# sql server 2000 data in view to xml file

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2000, bcp

I am trying to get data from a table and store it as XML File as shown in [Here](http://mdid.org/mdidwiki/index.php?title=How_to_export_data_from_SQL_Server_2000_to_XML).  In a view I created the following:

```
Select [name],[surname],[age] From Students
```

and from a stored procedure I want to call the view and write everything to an xmlFile as below:

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM DatabaseName..Students_View FOR XML Auto, Elements" queryout C:\data.xml -w -r "" -S sqlserver -T
```

I am getting the data correctly, the problem is I am not getting the xml header.  I know the example is using Explicit but in my case I need Auto.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checked better on the issue.  best way to move data from a table,view etc... to xml is to use FOR XML EXPLICIT and design the schema and structure as shown in the link given out in the question